# Какой примерно код должен быть в скрипте для NodeJS для выполнения серверного рендеринкга SPA на React?

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, reactjs, express, redux

Вопрос от новичнка в React. Имеется SPA React-приложение собранное при помощи Webpack. Все работает отлично. Запрос на сервер возвращает нам index.html без "полезного" контента, а только лишь с начальным скелетом разметки и с подключением файла bundle.js  внутри. Дальше bundle.js делает свое дело. Ходим-бродим по приложению - видим нужное наполнение на соответствующих страницах. Т.е. роуты работают, компоненты рендарятся и обновляются. Теперь нужно сделать так, чтоб при  запросе на сервер возвращалась страница уже наполненная соответствующим запрошенному УРЛу контентом. Т.е. чтоб bundle.js выполнился на сервере, а не на клиенте. Гуглил много. Выяснил, что это делается путем установки на сервер NodeJS и модуля Express. Тут тоже вроде все понятно. Непонятно, как выглядит примерно код скрипта для NodeJS, который будет принимать запрос от клиента и рендерить соответствующую страницу, т.е. выполнять соответствующий роут для запрошенного УРЛа из bundle.js используемого в index.html react-приложения. Может у кого-то есть пример кода, который решает подобную задачу? Ну, или ссылка на инфу по теме. Буду признателен!

Comment: [тыц](https://github.com/krambertech/spa-webinar)

Comment: Я так понял, это автор умеет. Просто отдавать по рест-апи данные для отрисовки на реакте. Его интересует, как сделать, чтобы реакт не рисовал на фронтенде гриды из данных с сервера, а чтобы отрабатывал по серверным роутам и рисовал на бэкэнде, а потом отправлял как html-верстку на фронт. Верно?

Comment: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-express-382591bfc77c  Сам не пробовал, но вот тут инфа есть вроде

Comment: @larrymacbarry да, именно так. Подумал, может кто из народа сталкивался с этим. Гугл это хорошо, но иногда требуется помощь джедаев ))

Comment: что у вас используется в качестве роутера? и что вы используете в качестве менеджера состояний?

Comment: @xFloooo роутер Router 4, меенеджер состояний Redux

Comment: ну тогда всё очень просто, для сервера от роутера вам нужен StaticRouter - в доке есть даже пример.
Для редакса вам нужно сгенерировать начальное состояние.
Опять же в документации к редаксу тоже есть пример Server Render.
Пакет Express вам нужен для поднятия сервера на node.
Все примеры распишу, попозже если кто то не опередит...

Comment: собственно статей по этой теме  довольно много https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=react+node+server+side+rendering&oq=react+node+server+s&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.9365j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Вам нужен сервер node + express

```
var App = require("./public/static/server/app").App; //ОБ этом дальше будет описано
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

// Принимаем все подряд GET запросы
app.get("*", function (req, res, next){
    var preloadState = preloadStateData(req)
    var renderData = App.getHTML(
        preloadState,
    );
    res.send(renderData.html);
});
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Running on http://localhost:");
});

function preloadStateData(req) {
    return {
        location: req.url,
        context: {},
        data: {
           ...ваш стейт
        }
    };
}
```

2 - Вам нужно 2 билда: 1-н для сервера, 2-й для клиента. В вебпаке делаете 2 сборки с разными точками входа. У меня это выглядит примерно так

```
var base = {...конфигурация}
var server = clone(base);
var client = clone(base);
client.entry = {
    app: ["babel-polyfill", "./application/client.js"]
}; 
client.output.path = __dirname + "/public/static/client";

server.entry = {
    app: ["babel-polyfill", "./application/server.js"]
};
server.output = {
    path: __dirname + "/public/static/server",
};
```

3 - `./application/client.js` - это ваше клиентское приложение оно остатёся таким же как и сейчас у вас, а вот `./application/server.js` - это уже реализация для серверной части. Небольшой пример:

```
let App = {
    getHTML: preloadState => {
        //Тут нужно заинициализировать вашу стору...
        let app = (
            <StaticRouter context={{}} location={preloadState.location}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Application />
                </Provider>
            </StaticRouter>
        );

        const html = <Html preloadState={preloadState} content={ReactDOMServer.renderToString(app)} />;

        let returnObj = {
            html: `<!doctype html>\n${ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
                html 
            )}`
        };

        return returnObj;
    }
};

function Html({ content, preloadState }) {
    return (
        <html>
            <head>
                <link
                    href="/app.css"
                    media="screen"
                    rel="stylesheet"
                    type="text/css"
                />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="root" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
                <script
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: `window.__PRELOAD_STATE__=${JSON.stringify(
                            preloadState.data
                        )};`
                    }}
                />
                <script src="/app.js" />
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}

module.exports = App;
```

В итоге мы рендерим реактом всю страницу. Спешил, мог понаделать ошибок, но общий план выглядит примерно так.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что при таком подходе когда запрос придет на сервер ему выдасться страница сгегерированная на сервере, а далее уже будет работать приложение на клиенте? Т.е. переход по ссылкам будет выполняться в рамках роутинга клинтского приложения и запросов на сервер уже не будет (кроме аяксовых к api т.п.)?

Comment: @Machez абсолютно верно

Comment: Спасибо! Буду копать!